# printing with Android eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, printing, adt

When I use System.out.println() with the Android ADT for Eclipse, it doesn't show in console?

How can I turn it on? or how to properly output to console with the ADT?

Answer (score 3):

System.out.println and Log.d both go to LogCat, not the Console.

Window->Show View->Other…->Android->LogCat

Comment: use Log.d and see it should appear.

Comment: It didn't show anything..I restarted eclipse and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Log.d("name", "log string"); for logging and then open the logcat to see the logs